# Java: how to pass reference to new operator?

Tags: java

I know that I can pass a reference of a method to another method, like this:

```
foo(Bar::doBar); // or e.g.
foo(bar::doBar); // or e.g.
foo(this::doBar);
```

Is it possible to pass a reference to `new` operator?

Android studio says that I ought to replace a line like this:

```
(a, b) -> new Pair<>(a, b)
```

with a method reference to new. But how do I do that?

Comment: If Android Studio gives you a hint, it can also do the transformation for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use

```
Pair<>::new
```

This will call the constructor.
This is also the preferred way to use `Optional.orElseThrow`:

```
list.stream().filter(...).findFirst().orElseThrow(MyException::new)
```

Because `new` is a keyword, there can't be a method called `new`, so there will be no ambiguity if this should mean a constructor or a method.

Comment: `.orElseThrow(MyException::new)` is not preferable at all - you set neither the message nor the cause... Just a fancy syntax :)

Comment: The resulting implementation will call it.

Answer (score 4):

A constructor reference is a special case of a [Method Reference Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13). As a small point of terminology, the reference is not to the *operator*, but to a *particular constructor*. If, for instance, `Pair<T>` had more than one constructor, the right one would be selected based on the static context.

Different ways to refer to a constructor (from [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13)):

```
ArrayList<String>::new     // constructor for parameterized type
ArrayList::new             // inferred type arguments
                           // for generic class
Foo::<Integer>new          // explicit type arguments
                           // for generic constructor
Bar<String>::<Integer>new  // generic class, generic constructor
int[]::new                 // array creation
```

Comment: it's worth mentioning that `ArrayList::new` never refers to a raw constructor